# SharePoint2010 content editor?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I am building a website that will make heavy use of the content editor webparts to allow for content to be added. The drawback to this is that by default the content editor provides a "Rich Text Editor" which is good for adding data but bad because it has the potential to break styling. I have two solutions :

First is to do some coding to somehow have predefined css styles added to the styles menu of the Rich text editor.

Second which should be quicker is to simply disable the Rich text editor i.e disabling the fonts, styles, etc from the Rich Text editor so that users can only enter data and not mess around with the styling.

For soultion two, is this possble and what would be the quickest way to achieve this?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of the rich text editor is to allow the user to enter styled content as they see fit. If you don't want any styling to be applied through the RTE either create style rules in your CSS to overrride anything the user enters or else use content fields based on multiple lines of text rather than rich text.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input. I have found this article that does exactly what I need. Simple! (http://blog.mastykarz.nl/consistent-content-authoring-sharepoint-2010-rich-text-editor/)

Comment: Another thing you can do is to write your own RTE control webpart which actually hosts the editor control. In your code behind you can then set the properties of the RTE control top restrict the level of options. See the following; http://msmvps.com/blogs/brianmadsen/archive/2008/03/14/sharepoint-using-the-rich-text-box-in-a-custom-user-control.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Core Technology Systems has recently released a how to video on content management on SharePoint 2010.  I have included a link to the website which has the link to the video and their YouTube channel.

http://coregb.com/blog/archive/2011/12/01/content-organiser-in-sharepoint2010.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are affiliated with the company it would be polite to say so.